# Xcode Osx drag to Browser

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, file, drag

I have a problem, that brings me head.

When I drag and drop an image on to an external browser from Finder, it recognizes it perfectly.

However, from the My App I have a file manager, and when I try to drag an image on to an external browser, is not recognized.

What do I have to do to recognize the image as a file?